# Outlook Add-in: Trouble Opening Dialogs from Pinnable Taskpane

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I’m a developer working on an add-in for Microsoft Outlook, and we are working on incorporating Pinnable Taskpane (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane) for more information about updating the manifest). I am running into issues launching dialogs on Outlook Web App for Office365 accounts using the function `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync`. When the taskpane is pinned and we are moving through emails, we cannot display dialogs in iframes after the first one. This issue seems to only be affecting OWA when we set the `displayInIframe` parameter to be `true`. Outlook 2016 on Windows is not affected, which we believe is because the desktop apps do not use the `displayInIframe` parameter.

Steps to Reproduce

1. Load a custom add-in with pinnable taskpane capability and the HTML below
2. Open a session of Outlook Web App in a new tab
3. Sign in to an Office365 account
4. Open an e-mail in read view and open the add-in (if the taskpane is
   not pinned, pin it)
5. From the add-in, click on the Launch Dialog button (the dialog
   should open)
6. Navigate to another email in read view
7. From the add-in, click on the Launch Dialog button (the dialog does
   not open)
8. From the add-in, click on the Launch Dialog button (we see a `12007`
   error -- dialog is already open)

This HTML includes printing out the `asyncResult` from launching the dialog, so you should be able to see detailed responses in the console. Is there something we are missing that is causing the dialog to be hidden?

HTML

```html
<button class="dialog-button">Click Here to Launch Dialog</button>
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 let testUrl = {{insert URL here}};
 $(document).ready(() => {
  $('.dialog-button').click(() => {
   Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(testUrl, {
         height: 90,
         width: 80,
         displayInIframe: true,
      }, (asyncResult) => {
       console.log('asyncResult: ',asyncResult);
       dialog = asyncResult.value;
       dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
      });
  });
 });

 let processMessage = (arg) => {
  dialog.close();
 }
</script>
```

Comment: I can confirm we repro the issue too. This looks to be a bug. Until we can investigate/resolve it, using displayInFrame = false is the best workaround. I did notice this doesn't repro in the latest OWA beta client (so that is another workaround).

Comment: Thanks for the response! 


From my understanding, the beta is only accessible to outlook.com users and not O365 users on outlook.office.com. Do we have a timeline / ETA for the bugfix?


Further, I have seen that when the displayInIframe parameter is set to false, the user is prompted to allow the add-in to open a new window (whether they have their taskpane pinned or not). Is there any way we can improve the user’s experience without degrading the the experience of the non-pinned users?  Can we recognize if the pane is pinned or not?

Comment: We have fixed the bug and the fix should be available in build 16.00.2527.000 or later. Depending on the release channel a customer is on, getting an updated build can take anywhere from 4-8 weeks.